# Attaining csv delimiter using birt scripting

Tags: csv, birt, export-to-csv

This might be a basic question, but being a beginner to Actuate Birt, i am posting this.

We have a requirement to change the de-limiter in CSV while exporting Birt CSV reports.

I came across the below CSV plug-in in the below site.

/designing-birt-reports/1417-csv-emitter-plugin-for-birt/">http://developer.actuate.com/community/devshare//designing-birt-reports/1417-csv-emitter-plugin-for-birt/

Instead of using Java code is there any way we can change the delimiter of CSV using Birt **before Factory** or other methods in Birt scripting?

I tried giving the below code in **Before factory** of the Birt script, but it didn't work.

```
// Creating CSV Render Option object here..
        csvOptions = new CSVRenderOption();
        var format = CSVRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_CSV;            

// CSV Render Options to specify the delimiter
        csvOptions.setDelimiter("\t");

// CSV Render Option to specify the character to be replaced if delimiter appears in actual text
        csvOptions.setReplaceDelimiterInsideTextWith("-");
```

Could someone help me out in this.